# How to sort a special character list the way I wanted in c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a function called OperatorSorter and I basically want to sort a special character list.
ex:

```
['-', '*', '/', '+', '^'] => ['^', '*', '/', '-', '+']
```

What I want to do is make a Calculator and it will make an operator list. But it has to order operations and it should sort them.
But I can't use their ascii's due to they are not in order this way.
May someone give me a good sort way to sort this in c++?

Comment: You have to code the comparison manually. For example with some datastructure that maps each character to the weight it should have when sorting.

Comment: this question looks like tip of iceberg of actual problem. Provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a mapping of sorts. For example consider the following, using `std::map`:

```
std::map<char, int> sortWeigths { {'^', 0} , {'*', 1} , {'/', 1} , {'-', 2} , {'+', 2} };
```

Where some operators have the same weights.
Then you can use a custom comparator like this:

```
bool CompareOperators(char a, char b)
{   
    return sortWeigths[a] < sortWeigths[b];
}
```

That's just the rough outline and I hope you get the idea.

Note that when using [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) identical elements might switch positions. E.G. input
`['-', '*', '/']` might end up as either `['*', '/', '-']` *or* `[ '/', '*', '-']`. If that's important consider [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only sort these characters. If you map (translate) the first character to, say 'a', the next in your preferred order to 'b', next to 'c' etc. then you can use a regular sort. After the sorting is done you map the characters back.
If two of your characters have equal value you need to handle those cases separately.

Comment: But there is a problem when * and / has same order to do

Comment: But you can't map the characters back, when two were mapped to the same char for sorting. Let's say * and / would both be mapped to 'b', because they should be considered equal when sorting. Now you have no way of determining what was * and what was /. Maybe that's not important, just a point to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create a map assigning keys to each symbol.  This way you can add new symbols if required.  Following key-value pairs are already sorted w.r.t the key.

```
#include <map>
std::map<int,char> symbol_map = {{1,'^',}, {2,'*'}, {3,'/'}, {4,'-'}, {5,'+'}};
std::multimap<int,char> symbol_map2 = {{1,'^',}, {2,'*'}, {2,'/'}, {3,'-'}, {3,'+'}};
```

Comment: Yes but its a problem when * and / has same priorty

Comment: Use BODMAS rule or create a multimap which can have multiple keys for different values.